# Offset can't return a div to 0,0?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm not sure if I'm having a reference frame problem but I have a pair of div elements pop up next to a target div which has variable positioning.

I'm using a fade, complete combination to hide the divs after a period of time and reset the position of each div to 0,0 however it seems that the reset is not happening

```
var div = $("#settings");
var position = div.position();
var xcor = position.left;
var ycor = position.top;
$( "#settings" ).offset({ top: ycor-ycor, left: xcor-xcor });
alert('requested offset');
```

this is part of the function that is called and the alert appears so that indicates to me that the five lines are parsed above.

I have also tried `top: -ycor, left: -xcor` alternatively I've tried 0,0

I have moved elements in a negative direction before eg. moving upwards by subtracting 1 and using set interval, but I just want to reset these back to 0,0, if there is an easier / more direct way to do that, that would be great... or skip the top-left corner origin idea entirely.

Comment: set using style, use css property of jquery

Comment: 1) put an alert in and confirm that your code is actually being called 2) ycor-ycor will always just be zero - so simplify... you want 0,0 so use 0,0. If that isn't working, it's not because you've failed to make it complicated enough, but because something else is going wrong... check all the other things first 3) eg check that you actually have a div in your div variable... then actually use that same div when calling offset.

Comment: I use alert all the time, as I said above I used it. I realize that ycor-ycor is zero, I mentioned slightly below that I also tried -ycor by itself but I think I'm going to skip this method entirely and go with the direct approach of CSS

Comment: can i post it as answer ?

Comment: yeah man, I'll re-update my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [CSS method of Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2)

```
 $( this ).css( "top", "topvalue" );

 $( this ).css( "left", "leftvalue" );
```

Hope this helps.